# Is there a list of available version of MSBuild to select from when building on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm running a solution that fails to build on Azure Pipelines on hosted agent 'macOs'.
In the log it says:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.224.30163 (xplat-master/d375bb6e Sat Jun 30 05:26:28 EDT 2018) for Mono
```

I'd like to use another version of MSBuild.

So the questions are:

1°) Can I select a version to build against?

2°) How do I know which versions are installed and available to select from?

Comment: On macOS, the only MSBuild version supported by Microsoft is the version bundled as `dotnet`, so you should use `dotnet build` instead of raw MSBuild commands. If you found yourself in need of MSBuild/Mono, that usually indicates that you are on a wrong/imporoper track. What kind of solution is it? You might find alternative ways.

Comment: I don't use MSBuild command directly, I run XamariniOS and XamarinAndroid tasks.

Comment: That starts to make some sense, but again raw MSBuild is not something you should go after. You should need to verify that the right version of Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android is there or not. It is possible that the hosted agent lags behind https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/647 So in many cases you should consider use a self-hosted agent.

Comment: I'm not saying I want to use a version that is not installed. I'm asking how can I know what version of MSBuild are installed and how can I pick one while still using the xamariniOS and xamarinAndroid tasks.

Comment: The Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS tasks suggest there is an input of `msbuildlocationOption`, `msbuildVersionOption`, that suggests you can change the version for the task. I would be careful to ensure you are using the correct version of MSBuild for the respective version of XA and XI. i.e. 16.0 for any Visual Studio 2019 equivalent Xamarin SDK builds. If the latest isn't what you want, contact their support since they should be in line with what the SDK needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1°) To change the version of MSBuild (as displayed in the log), I changed the version of Xamarin.

```
- bash: /bin/bash -c "sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh $(XamarinVersion)"
    displayName: Select Xamarin Version
```

2°) The available versions are listed in the [github repo of the hosted agent image.](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.14-Readme.md#mono)

Comment: You should accept your own answer. For future readers, more details can be found in Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-manually-select-versions-of-tools-on-the-hosted-macos-agent